# how to extend router range with a secondary router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, openwrt, wireless-bridge

How can I connect a secondary router(ROUTER B) to primary router(ROUTER A) via wifi so that clients from ROUTER B can connect to clients from ROUTER A and vice-versa?

here's an image of what I want(I hope it's clear) 
[image]

I succeeded(only half way..., using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rbsh2zxPnk) tutorial) to connect from ROUTER B to ROUTER A as client, and make an access point on ROUTER B, however, clients from ROUTER B can connect to clients from ROUTER A and internet, but, clients from ROUTER A cannot connect to clients from ROUTER B, in other words:

ROUTER B CLIENT X <-> ROUTER A CLIENT Z

ROUTER A CLIENT Z |-| ROUTER B CLIENT X

Comment: Did you enable and configure WDS in both routers?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, well, I tried, after your comment, performed a reset on ROUTER B and did the following: ROUTER A: the 2g wifi is set as Access Point WDS; on ROUTER B: joined the 2g network(AP WDS) as Client WDS, set LAN IP to 192.168.2.1(ROUTER A has 192.168.1.1) and disabled DHCP, on WWAN set static IP to 192.168.1.110 and disabled DHCP, set gateway and dns to 192.168.1.1; still can't access devices from ROUTER B from devices on ROUTER A(vice-versa works) what am I missing?

Comment: Why did you set the static IP to one outside the LAN? Is your LAN 192.168.1.x or 192.168.2.x? You only have one LAN, right? You're *bridging* between the two routers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because I don't know what I'm doing or what I am supposed to do :\ can you please guide me?

Comment: You're trying to create just one LAN. That means one router runs DHCP and all devices are numbered inside the same subnet.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you please be more specific, networking is beyond me... all I want is ROUTER B to be somehow connected to ROUTER A and clients from both routers to be able to communicate

Comment: That's what WDS does. Make sure only one device is doing DHCP. Make sure all devices with static IP addresses are numbered inside whatever subnet you choose to use for your LAN.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz based on your comment, it's unclear if secondary router must have static IP, or devices connected to it -- I don't want to assign static IP to devices...; can you post the setup of main router and secondary router as answer please? then I can test and accept your answer

Comment: The secondary router should either have a static address or no address (unless the router supports using DHCP to determine its LAN address, but I wouldn't recommend that even if it's supported). Devices connected to the secondary router are connected to the LAN, and the LAN has a DCHP server, so they can have dynamic addresses.